# React Query with Localstorage TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')` even though the app works correctly and the data is not null.

when I add optional chaining in useGetParcels() the error is gone but I cannot get the data or use invalidateQueries

Note: I'm setting data in localstorage after login

useGetParcels.tsx

```
import { getBikerParcels } from "@/models/bikerModels";
import { getSenderParcels } from "@/models/senderModels";
import { User } from "@/types/dataTypes";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const useGetParcels = (userData: User) => {
  return useQuery(
    ["user-parcels", userData?.id],
    async () => {
      let res;
      if (userData.type === "biker") {
        res = await getBikerParcels(userData.id);
      } else if (userData?.type === "sender") {
        res = await getSenderParcels(userData.id);
      }
      const parcels = res.data.parcels;
      return parcels;
    },
    {
      staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 100,
      enabled: userData.id.length > 0,
    }
  );
};

export default useGetParcels;
```

Page.tsx

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import SenderTable from "./senderTable";
import useLocalStorage from "@/hooks/useLocalStorage";
import BikerTable from "./bikerTable";
import useGetParcels from "@/hooks/queries/useGetParcels";
import Loading from "@/components/Loading";
import Nav from "@/components/Nav";

export default function Dashboard() {
  const [userData] = useLocalStorage("userData", null);
  const { data: parcels, isLoading, error } = useGetParcels(userData);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {userData?.type === "sender" && <Nav />}
      {userData?.type === "sender" ? (
        <SenderTable parcels={parcels} />
      ) : (
        <BikerTable parcels={parcels} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: On the first two lines of `function Dashboard` When there is nothing in local storage, userData is going to be null because you initialize it as null.  What should useGetParcels do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your `enabled` clause to check for boolean values only.
In your implementation, the userData can be null thus throwing the type error.

```
 enabled: !!userData?.id,
```